# R ggplot ggupset - Create inset with combinations that have fewer intersection

Tags: r, ggplot2, upsetr, upsetplot

I am looking for a way to subset my input data so I can make a second upsetR plot that shows the resolution of the sample intersections that are <<100 (for example). As an example, I'm using the tidy_movies data from tidyverse and the ggupset documentation (https://github.com/const-ae/ggupset).

I've posted a 'photoshopped' version of the figure that I need to make.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggupset)

#tidy_movies

tidy_movies %>%
  distinct(title, year, length, .keep_all=TRUE) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Genres)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_upset(n_intersections = 20)
  # + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,100)) ##This does not work when uncommented.
```

Ideally, want a figure that looks like this:

[image: examplefigure2]

Another approach would be to figure out how to subset tidy_movies

```
class(tidy_movies)
# How could I create a new version of tidy_movies that isolates a specific set of combinations?
```

thoughts? suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new column comprising the pasted-together contents of the `Genre` list column, `group_by` this, and filter out any groups with `n() > 100`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggupset)

tidy_movies %>%
  distinct(title, year, length, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(gen = sapply(Genres, paste, collapse = " ")) %>%
  group_by(gen) %>%
  filter(n() < 100) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Genres)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 200)) +
  scale_x_upset(n_intersections = 8)
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/12500315/allan-cameron, I am getting the following error when I run the above code. Can  you please help?

Comment: @RanonKahn what error?

Comment: Error in `geom_bar()`:
! Problem while mapping stat to aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `match.fun()`:
! 'scale$transformation$inverse' is not a function, character or symbol
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
Removed 100 rows containing non-finite outside the scale range (`stat_count()`).

Comment: When I tried to run the code suggested by you, I ran into the error.

Comment: @RanonKahn my code clearly works for the given data set. If you are having difficulties applying it to your own data please post a new question.

Comment: I appreciate your swift response. I will raise a question as suggested.

Comment: My bad! The code is working as expected. Thanks a lot.